# Margin before or after a table

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I'm trying to find a way to properly enforce margins around tables in Word 2016 without success. By default when you insert a paragraph after a table there will be no margin between the two, and inserting a blank line results in too much margin to my liking.

I fiddled with the table styles but their behavior are wonky. I would assume that defining a "space after" in the paragraph options for the table would do exactly what I want, however it creates a space after each cell, not after the table itself.

My second idea involved fiddling with paragraph styles and create a style specifically for paragraphs that immediately follow a table, with a "space before." This works but it feels more like a workaround than a real solution. Especially because I also have to create a new style for titles after tables and subtitles after tables etc.

So, how do you define the spacing around a table and save it inside a table style?

Comment: I'm not aware of such setting. As an improved workaround you may crate just one new style of which you put an empty paragraph after the table.